# Android Socket Client didn't send and closes itself

Tags: android, sockets, client

I am pretty new to android and java programming and I need your help. I want to create an Android client and a server on my PC (Windows 7). I checked with putty (a program which imitates a client (without programming mistakes^^)) whether my server is programmed without mistakes. Thereby I recognized that my server is programmed correctly.

Here you can see my well-working server:

```
  public class MyServer {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

  try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4449);
      System.out.println("Listening on port: 4449");
  } catch (IOException e){
      System.err.println("Could not listen on port 4449.");
      System.exit(1);
  }

  Socket clientSocket = null;

  try {
      clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
   System.out.println("Got connection.");
  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Accept failed: 4449.");
      System.exit(1);
  }

  BufferedReader in = null;
  PrintWriter out = null;
  try {
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

      out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Read failed");
      e.printStackTrace();
  }


  try {

      System.out.println("message: " + in.readLine());
      out.println("hab was bekommen!");
  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Can't get a message from Client.");
      e.printStackTrace();

  }
  }
  }
```

I also tried to create an Android client for this server, but i didn't managed it.

Here is my Mainactivity:

```
public class AndroidClient extends Activity {

EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;
TextView problems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_client);

    textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
    Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
    problems = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.problems);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener 
= new Button.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Socket client = null;


        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try {
            client = new Socket("192.168.2.107", 4449);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            problems.setText("Unknown host: 192.168.2.107");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // System.out.println("No Input/Output.");
            problems.setText("No Input/Output.");
        }

        try {
            out.println("Hallo.");
            textIn.setText(in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            problems.setText("Can't send/ get message.");
        }
    }   
};



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_android_client, menu);
    return true;
}
    }
```

So far so good. When i start my app on my android smartphone the app starts without any problem. Then i type something in my EditText field 'textOut' und pushed to 'Send' button. Then my screen gets black and the app closes itself. I also pasted the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml to enter the internet and to use access Wifi.

I hope that someone can help me, because i am working on this problem for 2 days and haven't found any solution yet. I mainly used this side (http://android-er.blogspot.de/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html) and of course some other sides, but there i got most information. Furthermore there are no shown mistakes in my source code.

With kind regards,

Lukas5060

edit: Here is my LogCat:

12-28 20:21:55.929: I/dalvikvm(698): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 20:21:56.039: I/dalvikvm(698): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 20:21:56.259: I/dalvikvm(698): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 20:21:56.299: I/dalvikvm(698): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 20:21:56.741: D/gralloc_goldfish(698): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-28 20:21:56.771: I/dalvikvm(698): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 20:21:56.789: I/dalvikvm(698): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 20:23:58.430: D/AndroidRuntime(698): Shutting down VM
12-28 20:23:58.430: W/dalvikvm(698): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:177)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:149)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at net.ibasic.AndroidClient$1.onClick(AndroidClient.java:50)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-28 20:23:58.470: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 20:23:59.070: I/dalvikvm(698): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-28 20:23:59.100: I/dalvikvm(698): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-28 20:24:02.420: I/Process(698): Sending signal. PID: 698 SIG: 9

Comment: If this happens you usually get some error output from logcat, can you post that aswell?

Comment: I changed the ip and run it on my pc with android sdk. here is my logcat. i hopee you can see there my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my guess is that the problem is that your doing this in the main ui thread which is far from recommended. Instead what you should do is checkout `AsyncTask` which is the preferred way of doing this kind of operations (reading from files or web and a bunch of other stuff).

This is easier than it sounds what you need to do is something like this (note this is just to give you a feeling about how it looks):

```
private class CreateSocketTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Do the socket stuff here...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //This is called when doInBackground has finished
        //From here you'd call a method in the main ui class.
    }
}
```

Heres the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

There are a bunch of tutorials on the net so you'll be up and running in no time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I hope this will work and i am going to try this right now.